# Overloading an EL function defined in TLD

Tags: jsp, el

Is it possible to overload(function name) an EL function? Please look at following piece of TLD:

Same function name `rollDice`

```
<function>  
<name>rollIt</name>  
<function-class>com.Person</function-class>  
<function-signature>int rollDice()</function-signature>  
</function>  

<function>  
<name>rollIt</name>  
<function-class>com.Person</function-class>  
<function-signature>int rollDice(int)</function-signature>  
</function>
```

Answer (score 3):

No, EL functions do unfortunately not support method overloading (nor varargs). Give each function a different name.

Comment: EL function support the varargs and array
<function>
  <name>functionname</name>
  <function-class>com.test.SomeClass</function-class>
  <function-signature>java.lang.String functionname(java.lang.Long...)</function-signature>
 </function>

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in a TLD-defined function, but you can put an object on the application scope (once, at start-up) with a varags method and/or overloaded methods, and have that work fine.

Instead of defining it in a TLD, you can, in your servlet's `init()` method, you create an instance of your class and place it in the application (servlet) scope, like so:

```
MyDiceRoller roller = new MyDiceRoller();
ServletContext context = getServletContext();
context.setAttribute("roller", roller);
```

Then, instead of `${my:rollIt(6)}`, you would do `${roller.rollIt(6)}`. And instead of `${my:rollIt()}`, you would do `${roller.rollIt()}`.